# Is a $k[G]$-module which is free on every cyclic subgroup free?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $M$ be a representation of $G$ over a field $k$. Suppose that, for every cyclic subgroup $C$ of $G$, we have $M|_{C} \cong k[C]^{\oplus [G:C]}$. Can we conclude that $M \cong k[G]$?

In characteristic zero, this is immediately true by character theory, but I don't know what happens in finite characteristic.

**Motivation:** I was thinking about the normal basis theorem in Galois theory, and I remembered that many sources do the cyclic case separately. Suppose that $M/k$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Then, for each cyclic subgroup $C$, we know that $M/\text{Fix}(C)$ is a Galois extension with Galois group $C$ so, if we knew the normal basis theorem for cyclic extensions, we would know that $M \cong \text{Fix}(C)[C] \cong k[C]^{\oplus [G:C]}$ as a $k[C]$-module. I was wondering whether this might already be enough to finish the proof with no more field theory input.

Comment: Let $k$ be algebraically closed of char. $p$ and let $M$ be finitely generated. By results of Chouinard and Dade, a $kG$-module is projective iff its restriction to every shifted cyclic subgroup of order $p$ is projective. Since projective modules over the $k$-group algebra of $p$-groups are free, $M$ is projective over $kG$ iff its restriction to every shifted cyclic subgroup of order $p$ is free. ...

Comment: ... In particular, your question (extended to shifted cyclic subgroups) has an affirmative answer if $G$ is a $p$-group and conversely, each projective $kG$-module that is not free, should provide a counterexample.

Comment: @tj_ Thanks! There must be a missing hypothesis in your second comment though. For example, if $p$ does not divide $|G|$, then the trivial module $k$ is a summand of $kG$ and is thus projective and not free, but it doesn't give a counterexample. And there are less trivial examples ...

Comment: Yes, of course, $p$ is supposed to divide the order of $G$ throughout. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Can you combine cyclic shifted subgroups with character theory? What if a representation is free when restricted to every abelian subgroup? Then by Dade, it is free when restricted to the $p$-Sylow subgroup and by character theory it is free when restricted to all the other Sylow subgroups. But how do they mix together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose that $E = C_p \times \dots \times C_p$ be an elementary abelian $p$-group, say of rank $r$, and let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Then the group algebra $kE$ is isomorphic to $k[x_1, \dots, x_r]/(x_1^p, \dots, x_r^p)$. If $v$ is in the vector space spanned by the $x_i$, then $(1+v)^p=1$, so $1+v$ generates a subgroup of the group of units of $kE$. This is called a *cyclic shifted subgroup* of $kE$.

A result of Dade originally, then independently later proved by Carlson and Avrunin-Scott, says the following: A $kE$-module $M$ is free if and only if the restriction of $M$ to each cyclic shifted subgroup is free.

(Dade: Lemma 11.8 in Endo-Permutation Modules over p-Groups II, https://www.jstor.org/stable/1971169. Carlson: Theorem 4.4 in The varieties and the cohomology ring of a module, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869383901217.)

I believe that there are examples of modules which restrict to free modules over every honest cyclic subgroup but not over every cyclic shifted subgroup, but I don't have one at my fingertips. There should be an example with $G = C_2 \times C_2$, I think.

Comment: Here is a $C_2 \times C_2$ example. Let $X$ and $Y$ be $2 \times 2$ matrices such that $X$, $Y$ and $X+Y$ are all invertible. Let $U = \begin{bmatrix} \text{Id}_2 & X \\ 0 & \text{Id}_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $V = \begin{bmatrix} \text{Id}_2 & Y \\ 0 & \text{Id}_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\langle U, V \rangle \cong C_2 \times C_2$.  The matrices $U$, $V$ and $UV$ all have Jordan form $\begin{bmatrix} \text{Id}_2 & \text{Id}_2 \\ 0 & \text{Id}_2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, so $k^4$ is free as a $k[U]$, $k[V]$ or $k[UV]$-module. But $1+U+V+UV=0$, so this isn't a free $k[C_2 \times C_2]$ module.